# Can't get accurate file size

Tags: c#, .net, filesize, fileinfo

This is how I try to get the file size in MB:

```
    FileInfo file_size = new FileInfo(list[i]);
    double friendly_file_size = (file_size.Length / 1048576);
    MessageBox.Show(friendly_file_size.ToString());
```

The problem is it does not show anything after comma.. when the file size is 3.15, it says 3. When it is 0.5, is says 0, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an integer division.  Turn it into a floating point division by making at least one of the operands a floating pointer number:

```
 double friendly_file_size = file_size.Length / 1048576.0;
```

or:

```
 double friendly_file_size = (double)file_size.Length / 1048576;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a numeric suffix (i.e. **1048576d**). It's mostly useful if you want to use decimal types though, and that shouldn't be necessary in this case.

Comment: @Thorarin: I wasn't aware [d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) was decimal, I was under the impression [that m was](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @Brad: `d` is `double`; `m` is `decimal` (money) -- however, in general English usage, `double` values represent decimal numbers, so Thorarin wasn't exactly wrong.

Comment: @Gabe: Freudian slip on my part, referenced the page and yet still reversed them in comment (must be bed time).

Comment: @Brad: the example Hans posted was using a double, so the alternative I posted used a double as well. Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 5):

Since your denominator is an integer, I suspect a cast is forcing integer division.  The solution is simple.  Just cast the denominator to a double.  Like this:

```
double friendly_file_size = file_size.Length / (double)1048576;
```